# Select all objects with specific position

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of all objects that have specific position. For example, get me all objects that have `(x,y,z) < 1`. How do I do this?

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.context.scene.objects

for obj in objects:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import bpy

objects = bpy.data.objects

lis = [obj for obj in objects if obj.location.x < 1 and obj.location.y < 1 and obj.location.z < 1]

# or
lis = []
for obj in objects:
    if obj.location.x < 1:
        if obj.location.y < 1:
            if obj.location.z < 1:
                lis.append(obj)
```

Comment: Hi thank you. I get a list here and is there a way to select all the objects that satisfies this condition?

Comment: `for obj in lis: obj.select_set(True)`